# Check if clicked element is descendant of parent, otherwise remove parent element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a script in vanilla JS (no jQuery) that will remove an element from the page if someone clicks outside of this element.

However, this `div` has many nested elements and the way I had it set up is that it disappears even by clicking an element that is within the first element.

Example markup:

```
<div id='parent-node'>
  This is the Master Parent node
  <div id ='not-parent-node'>
     Not Parent Node
    <button>Button</button>
    <div id='grandchild-node'>
      Grandbaby Node
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I would like that no matter how deeply nested an element is, it will check to see if its a descendant of the `<div id='parent-node'>` element. So if I click there, it will not get rid of the parent node and all its descendants. The `div` and its descendants should *ONLY* be removed dynamically when clicking outside of the parent `div`.

Currently this is what I have and I do know there are some serious fallacies in what I wrote:

```
function remove(id) {
    return (elem = document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    remove('parent-node');
});
```

Comment: You're right, this has been asked many, many times. What's wrong the [existing solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)? (It's trivial to adapt this from jQuery to vanilla JS)

Comment: Why adapt from jQuery? It's always better to learn the JavaScript basics first and **then** one can deal with libraries like jQuery. Especially if someone **wants** to as mentioned in the question!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Since [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is a reference to the clicked element, you can check to see if `#parent-node` is `event.target` or if it [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) `event.target` as a descendant element.

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/jwz4mwuj/)

In the snippet below, an event listener is attached to the document. If the element that triggered the click event *isn't* a descendant of `#parent-node` and *isn't* `#parent-node`, then the element is removed.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var element = document.getElementById('parent-node');

  if (e.target !== element && !element.contains(e.target)) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var element = document.getElementById('parent-node');
  
  if (e.target !== element && !element.contains(e.target)) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  }
});
```

```css
#parent-node {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent-node'>
  This is the Master Parent node
  <div id='not-parent-node'>
    Not Parent Node
    <button>Button</button>
    <div id='grandchild-node'>
      Grandbaby Node
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. The keys here are `target` and `contains`.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I googled my specific question and this exactly answered it. Wanted to implement clicking/tapping anywhere outside of a homemade modal would close it. Works perfectly.

Comment: Excellent thanks so much for this answer!

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to determine if the [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) has the id `#parent-node` or if it is a descendant (`#parent-node *`).

Then, you can use [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) to delete the `parent-node` element if the condition is `false`:

```
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (!event.target.matches('#parent-node, #parent-node *')) {
    document.getElementById('parent-node').remove();
  }
});
```