# Check if clicked element is descendant of parent( React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a react native project and i want to remove a view from the screen when the user clicks outside it's boundaries, Kinda like this but in react native [Similar example with vanilla JS on web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621987/check-if-clicked-element-is-descendant-of-parent-otherwise-remove-parent-elemen)

For example clicking outside the pink box should remove the box
but clicking any of the pink box's children should not.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.box}>
      <View style={styles.child}></View>
      <View style={styles.child}></View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'},
  box: {backgroundColor: 'pink', width: 200, aspectRatio: '1/1', justifyContent: "space-around"}, 
  child: {backgroundColor: "indigo", height: 40}
});
```

Comment: Checkout this library https://github.com/dcangulo/react-native-outside-press

Comment: Thanks @nucleartux this works. But is there a way to do this without depending on a library